What is this 1917 WW1 shell casing?
Can anybody help identify an apparent 1917 shell casing with the following information.  (Mm measurements may be a a mm or 2 off). The casing is 135mm tall and 45mm wide. There is a 1mm rim at the bottom and a slight taper on the top.
The markings on the bottom of the casing are around the primer hole (empty). Top has 2 lines.1st is: WPS CO. 2nd is:1917. At three o-clock is: JBS. At six o-clock is 1-Pdr. The Dr is caps but smaller than the preceding P. Under this marking is the symbol of an anchor. At nine o-clock there is 2 line entry. The top is Lot and on the bottom is the number 93.


It's a US Navy 1 pounder shell for the Pom-Pom AA Gun, manufactured by the Worcester Pressed Steel Company in, predictably, 1917.

Huh. So there were actually specialized anti-aircraft guns in WWI. That's something I learned today.

Are you certain that 1917 is the date of manufacture and not of the design?  For example, the 30-06 is so called because it was adopted as a standard in 1906.  The date of manufacture would be determined from the lot number.
